# Port Forward in Empty Port. But 'cannot listen to port' And The port is filled

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, networking, port-forwarding

#### Step 1. Checking Ports

```
netstat -tnlpa
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)  
Active Internet connections (servers and established)  
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6443          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -  
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

#### Step 2. Try SSH

```
ssh -N -f -L 8888:localhost:8888 -p 5000 one@destination.com
> No response.
```

#### Step 3. ReTry SSH

```
ssh -N -f -L 8888:localhost:8888 -p 5000 one@destination.com
bind [127.0.0.1]:8888: Address already in use  
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8888  
Could not request local forwarding.
```

#### Step 4. Checking Ports

```
netstat -tnlpa 
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info  
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)  
Active Internet connections (servers and established)  
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6443          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      228/ssh  
tcp        0      0 172.23.246.199:46180    20.194.107.22:5000      ESTABLISHED 228/ssh  
tcp        0      0 172.23.246.199:46182    20.194.107.22:5000      ESTABLISHED 230/ssh  
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -  
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8888                :::*                    LISTEN      228/ssh
```

Local: WSL2 LTS 20.04
Server: AzureVM LTS 18.0X

---

I'm sorry for not explaining enough due to my poor English skills and computer science knowledge.
If we need more information, I will respond.

Comment: What the problem is?

Comment: The problem appears to be that the first `ssh -L 8888:....` command seems to hang, and the re-try of the same `ssh -L 8888:...` command returns the error that port 8888 is already in use.

Comment: "no response" is due to the combination of `-N` + `-f`: no command and then continue running ssh in background (invisible). The first command (with no response) appears to have worked. There is no actual problem happening.

Comment: @SottoVoce I got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @A.B Oh My mistake. I erroneously copied the material online because I lacked Linux and networking knowledge. I only wanted port forwarding, so I left the L and p options, and as a result it works flawlessly. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll still leave a full answer because I was about to finish typing it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options provided for the first command (with no response) have the effect that when the command succeeds, there's no feedback:

- [`-N`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh.1l#N): don't run any remote command, that's useful when only forwarding ports.
- [`-f`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh.1l#f): when the authentication phase (if any) is over, the ssh command goes to background.

Thus the first command has no visible result, but did work as intended: setup the tunnel to forward the port 8888 and nothing else (that is visible).

The 2nd command succeeded only partially: it still ran a 2nd remote SSH connection in background, but could not forward *again* the same port: it was already done by the previous command. So it complained about this. Such SSH command which creates no tunnel and doesn't allow any command is just wasted resources.

---

What can be done better? It depends on the goal. But what can simply be done to prevent wasting resources is to force an SSH command that couldn't establish the requested tunnel to completely fail by using an additional option: `-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes`:

> Specifies whether ssh(1) should terminate the connection if it cannot
> set up all requested dynamic, tunnel, local, and remote port
> forwardings, [...]

So in the end you should run, once, but that's not a real issue to try more than once except getting an error message:

```
ssh -N -f -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -L 8888:localhost:8888 -p 5000 one@destination.com
```

Before this command can succeed, the previously running ssh commands (OP ran at least two of them) should be terminated first: one of them actually bound to port 8888 and will prevent this one to succeed.

On Linux their PID might possibly be found with this single `ss` command:

```
ss -tnp dst == destination.com and dport == 5000
```

so they can be killed with the `kill` command.